# Help with GPG error. NO_PUB_KEY

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, mysql

I know this has been anwsered several times but I tried everything and I'm still getting:

> W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
> W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

I tried `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C` and i get

> Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.vcmEU9jehS/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
> keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C gpg: key
> B7B3B788A8D3785C: "MySQL Release Engineering
> mysql-build@oss.oracle.com" not changed gpg: Total number processed:
> 1 gpg:              unchanged: 1

I tried:

> sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  B7B3B788A8D3785C sudo
> gpg -a --export B7B3B788A8D3785C | sudo apt-key add - sudo apt-get
> update

and i get:

> gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
> gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

And the error persists, any ideas? I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS x86_64
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead trying to add the GPG key manually, it is recommended to follow the [official instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/):

1. Look at `find /etc | grep -i mysql` and remove your previous attempt at installing the repository
2. Do `sudo apt purge mysql-apt-config` to remove the previous version if it is installed
3. Download the file from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/
4. Run `sudo dpkg -i ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.29-1_all.deb`
5. Select "OK" by pressing <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Run `sudo apt update`

The official package to add the repositories will correctly install the GPG key for you.

Comment: thanks! i'll try that, the strange thing is that i'm getting this error some days ago, it appeared by itself, i mean i was already using mysql