# Error when installing mysql-server on Ubuntu Desktop through apt

Tags: apt, 22.04, mysql

I am installing mysql-server on Ubuntu Desktop through apt.It shows that Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code. The concrete output of my terminal shows below(Note that I am in the root user and I execute three commands `apt purge mysql-server` `apt update` `apt install mysql-server -y`):

```shell
root@commie:/home/commie# apt purge mysql-server               # 1
正在读取软件包列表... 完成
正在分析软件包的依赖关系树... 完成
正在读取状态信息... 完成                 
软件包 mysql-server 未安装，所以不会被卸载
升级了 0 个软件包，新安装了 0 个软件包，要卸载 0 个软件包，有 0 个软件包未被升级。
root@commie:/home/commie# apt update               # 2
命中:1 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                         
获取:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [3,589 B]                                                                                                                 
命中:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                                          
命中:4 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                          
命中:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                                                              
命中:6 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                   
命中:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu jammy InRelease  
命中:8 https://packages.redis.io/deb jammy InRelease             
命中:9 https://scala.jfrog.io/artifactory/debian all InRelease
忽略:10 https://scala.jfrog.io/artifactory/debian  InRelease
命中:11 https://scala.jfrog.io/artifactory/debian  Release
已下载 3,589 B，耗时 5秒 (655 B/s)
正在读取软件包列表... 完成
正在分析软件包的依赖关系树... 完成
正在读取状态信息... 完成                 
所有软件包均为最新。
root@commie:/home/commie# apt install mysql-server -y               # 3
正在读取软件包列表... 完成
正在分析软件包的依赖关系树... 完成
正在读取状态信息... 完成                 
将会同时安装下列软件：
  libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-template-perl libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8
  mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
建议安装：
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
下列【新】软件包将被安装：
  libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-template-perl libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8
  mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
升级了 0 个软件包，新安装了 19 个软件包，要卸载 0 个软件包，有 0 个软件包未被升级。
需要下载 0 B/29.0 MB 的归档。
解压缩后会消耗 241 MB 的额外空间。
正在预设定软件包 ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 mysql-common。
(正在读取数据库 ... 系统当前共安装有 329115 个文件和目录。)
准备解压 .../0-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.8_all.deb  ...
正在解压 mysql-common (5.8+1.0.8) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 mysql-client-core-8.0。
准备解压 .../1-mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 mysql-client-8.0。
准备解压 .../2-mysql-client-8.0_8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libaio1:amd64。
准备解压 .../3-libaio1_0.3.112-13build1_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 libaio1:amd64 (0.3.112-13build1) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64。
准备解压 .../4-libevent-core-2.1-7_2.1.12-stable-1build3_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.12-stable-1build3) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64。
准备解压 .../5-libevent-pthreads-2.1-7_2.1.12-stable-1build3_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.12-stable-1build3) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libmecab2:amd64。
准备解压 .../6-libmecab2_0.996-14build9_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-14build9) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 mysql-server-core-8.0。
准备解压 .../7-mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
正在设置 mysql-common (5.8+1.0.8) ...
update-alternatives: 使用 /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback 来在自动模式中提供 /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf)
正在选中未选择的软件包 mysql-server-8.0。
(正在读取数据库 ... 系统当前共安装有 329328 个文件和目录。)
准备解压 .../00-mysql-server-8.0_8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libcgi-pm-perl。
准备解压 .../01-libcgi-pm-perl_4.54-1_all.deb  ...
正在解压 libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libfcgi0ldbl:amd64。
准备解压 .../02-libfcgi0ldbl_2.4.2-2build2_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 libfcgi0ldbl:amd64 (2.4.2-2build2) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libfcgi-perl:amd64。
准备解压 .../03-libfcgi-perl_0.82+ds-1build1_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 libfcgi-perl:amd64 (0.82+ds-1build1) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libcgi-fast-perl。
准备解压 .../04-libcgi-fast-perl_1%3a2.15-1_all.deb  ...
正在解压 libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libfcgi-bin。
准备解压 .../05-libfcgi-bin_2.4.2-2build2_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 libfcgi-bin (2.4.2-2build2) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 libhtml-template-perl。
准备解压 .../06-libhtml-template-perl_2.97-1.1_all.deb  ...
正在解压 libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 mecab-utils。
准备解压 .../07-mecab-utils_0.996-14build9_amd64.deb  ...
正在解压 mecab-utils (0.996-14build9) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 mecab-ipadic。
准备解压 .../08-mecab-ipadic_2.7.0-20070801+main-3_all.deb  ...
正在解压 mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 mecab-ipadic-utf8。
准备解压 .../09-mecab-ipadic-utf8_2.7.0-20070801+main-3_all.deb  ...
正在解压 mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
正在选中未选择的软件包 mysql-server。
准备解压 .../10-mysql-server_8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_all.deb  ...
正在解压 mysql-server (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
正在设置 libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-14build9) ...
正在设置 mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
正在设置 libfcgi0ldbl:amd64 (2.4.2-2build2) ...
正在设置 libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
正在设置 libfcgi-bin (2.4.2-2build2) ...
正在设置 libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
正在设置 mecab-utils (0.996-14build9) ...
正在设置 libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.12-stable-1build3) ...
正在设置 mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
正在设置 libfcgi-perl:amd64 (0.82+ds-1build1) ...
正在设置 libaio1:amd64 (0.3.112-13build1) ...
正在设置 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.12-stable-1build3) ...
正在设置 mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################| 

done!
update-alternatives: 使用 /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic 来在自动模式中提供 /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary)
正在设置 libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
正在设置 mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
正在设置 mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-3) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################| 

done!
update-alternatives: 使用 /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 来在自动模式中提供 /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary)
正在设置 mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: 使用 /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf 来在自动模式中提供 /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf)
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
指定的文件名 /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 不存在。
mysqld: Can't open shared library '/opt/mysql-8.2.0-linux-glibc2.28-x86_64/lib/mysql/plugin/component_reference_cache.so' (errno: 0 /opt/mysql-8.2.0-linux-glibc2.28-x86_64/lib/mysql/plugin/component_reference_cache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such f)
mysqld: Cannot load component from specified URN: 'file://component_reference_cache'.
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2024-03-03T08:59:20.104779Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-03-03 16:59:20 CST; 4ms ago
    Process: 7837 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 7845 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 7845 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"
      Error: 13 (权限不够)
        CPU: 273ms
dpkg: 处理软件包 mysql-server-8.0 (--configure)时出错：
 已安装 mysql-server-8.0 软件包 post-installation 脚本 子进程返回错误状态 1
dpkg: 依赖关系问题使得 mysql-server 的配置工作不能继续：
 mysql-server 依赖于 mysql-server-8.0；然而：
  软件包 mysql-server-8.0 尚未配置。

dpkg: 处理软件包 mysql-server (--configure)时出错：
 依赖关系问题 - 仍未被配置
因为错误消息指示这是由于上一个问题导致的错误，没有写入 apport 报告。
                                                                    正在处理用于 man-db (2.10.2-1) 的触发器 ...
正在处理用于 libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) 的触发器 ...
在处理时有错误发生：
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@commie:/home/commie#
```

If any information else is needed please feel free to tell me!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is there a way you can translate the error messaging into English? You may get more help that way.

Comment: If any version of MySQL (or MariaDB) was previously installed, it may not be enough to simply `apt purge` the previous installation away. Some directories will need to be manually removed before trying to install again.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's MySQL should not have `/opt/mysql-8.2.0-linux-glibc2.28-x86_64/`. Let's remove the broken version and install the official version.

1. Remove or move away unwanted packages and files:

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get purge '*mysql*'
   sudo mv /opt /opt.bak
   sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local.bak
   sudo rm -rf /usr/sbin/mysqld /usr/share/mysql
   sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bak

   sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d.bak
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   ```
2. Retry installing MySQL server:

   ```bash
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt full-upgrade
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```

Also look in `echo $LD_PRELOAD ; echo $PATH` and `/etc/ld.so.conf...` for anything that was added by the old installation before moving the things you want to keep from `/opt` and `/usr/local` back. If you wanted a newer version, you could have used the [MySQL repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/1502524/1004020), but even that doesn't install anything in `/opt`.